# Elemento dinámico se encuentra presente en respuesta, con Selenium

Tags: html, python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

Tengo la siguiente respuesta de un web service, en la cual los segmentos (< divs>) son objetos traídos desde la base de datos dinamicamente, con una estructura similar a la adjunta:

```html
<html>

<head></head>

<body>
<table style="width:100%">
  <tr>
    <th>
    <div id="OBJBDD543">
     ...
     ..
    </div>
    </th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th>
    <div id="OBJBDD134">
     ...
     ..
    </div>
    </th>
  </tr>
    <th>
    <div id="OBJBDD123">
     ...
     ..
    </div>
    </th>
  </tr>
</table>
</body>

</html>
```

Y cuando la respuesta se encuentra errada, carga el table pero sin los segmentos(< divs>) dentro, como se encuentra a continuación:

```html
<html>

<head></head>

<body>
<table style="width:100%">
  <tr>
  </tr>
  <tr>
  </tr>
</table>
</body>

</html>
```

La pregunta es la siguiente, existe alguna forma con selenium(python) de verificar si el table trajo los segmentos (divs).?

Comment: No sé si entendí bien la pregunta, pero puedes hacer un `if` donde preguntes por ejemplo `driver.find_elements_by_css_selector('th > div') != [] `

Comment: O sea me gustaria saber si en la pagina se encuentran ciertos elementos, pero como son dinamicos sus IDs, no puedo buscarlos por ```self.driver.find_element_by_id ```.

Comment: Si, entiendo, pero no puedes usar `selector css `como te he comentado?

Comment: Estoy intentado guardar el valor en una variable pero al momento de imprimirlo me retorna [].
El selector completo para mi web seria: ```tabla = self.driver.find_element_by_css_selector('#OBJ1210 > table > tbody > tr > td')```

Comment: Quiza algo se encuentra errado ?